# Nancy Error 503 AND The status code is Error with message '"' is an unexpected token. Expecting white space. Line 1, position 50

Tags: c#, .net, api, postman, nancy

Hi I keep getting the above error when I try to connect to our api (found through our logs for our front end. Our API log doesn't show anything for the attempted connection).

> 2018-06-21 13:51:28,289 INFO 
>   ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Base.Connector.Handlers.AbstractVERBHandler`1[[ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Base.Infrastructure.Responses.POSTResponseDto`1[[ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Proposals.ProposalQuoteDto,
>   ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs, Version=1.0.1.3789, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]], ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs, Version=1.0.1.3789,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] - Called
>   http://dev.ourPlatformName.api/proposalheader/35245/GetQuote (POST), the
>   response was OK 2018-06-21 13:51:28,294 INFO 
>   ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Base.Connector.Handlers.AbstractVERBHandler`1[[ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Base.Infrastructure.Responses.POSTResponseDto`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Reports.Base.ReportDto,
>   ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs, Version=1.0.1.3789, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs,
>   Version=1.0.1.3789, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] - Called
>   http://dev.ourPlatformName.api/reports/criteria (POST), the response was
>   ServiceUnavailable 2018-06-21 13:51:28,294 ERROR
>   ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Base.Connector.Plumbing.RestClientFailureHandler -
>   Call to API http://dev.ourPlatformName.api/reports/criteria (POST) caused
>   client failure. The status code is Error with message '"' is an
>   unexpected token. Expecting white space. Line 1, position 50.
>   2018-06-21 13:51:28,296 ERROR
>   ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Base.Connector.Handlers.POSTHandler`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Reports.Base.ReportDto,
>   ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs, Version=1.0.1.3789, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] - Failed to execute
>   ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Reports.Base.Criteria.ReportCriteriaDto. The
>   exception message is Call to API
>   http://dev.ourPlatformName.api/reports/criteria (POST) caused client
>   failure. **The status code is Error with message '"' is an unexpected
>   token. Expecting white space. Line 1, position 50.    at**
>   ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Base.Connector.Plumbing.RestClientFailureHandler.Handle(IRestResponse
>   response) in
>   f:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f559f7ce21491053\app\ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs\Base\Connector\Plumbing\RestClientFailureHandler.cs:line
>   29    at
>   ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Base.Connector.Plumbing.DefaultResponseHandler.Handle(IRestResponse
>   response) in
>   f:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f559f7ce21491053\app\ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs\Base\Connector\Plumbing\DefaultResponseHandler.cs:line
>   23    at
>   ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Base.Connector.Handlers.AbstractVERBHandler`1.ExecuteRequest(String
>   url, Method method, Object body, Func`2 onError, Boolean
>   authenticate) in
>   f:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f559f7ce21491053\app\ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs\Base\Connector\Handlers\AbstractVERBHandler.cs:line
>   57
>
> 2018-06-21 13:51:29,992 ERROR
>   ourPlatformName.Web.Infrastructure.ActionFilters.LogErrorAttribute - Request
>   unsuccessful- controller:quote action:email 2018-06-21 13:51:29,992
>   ERROR ourPlatformName.Web.Controllers.BaseController - Request unsuccessful
>   ourPlatformName.Web.Infrastructure.ourPlatformNameException: Request unsuccessful 
>   at
>   ourPlatformName.Web.Infrastructure.Extensions.ApiResponseDtos.ResponseErrorMessageExtensions.ThrowExceptionOnFailure(BaseResponseDto
>   dto) in
>   D:\code\ourPlatformName_EmailError\testRegion\ourPlatformName.web\app\ourPlatformName.Web.Infrastructure\Extensions\ApiResponseDtos\ResponseErrorMessageExtensions.cs:line
>   22    at
>   ourPlatformName.Web.Infrastructure.Extensions.ApiResponseDtos.PostResponseDtoExtensions.ThrowExceptionOnFailure[T](POSTResponseDto`1
>   responseDto) in
>   D:\code\ourPlatformName_EmailError\testRegion\ourPlatformName.web\app\ourPlatformName.Web.Infrastructure\Extensions\ApiResponseDtos\PostResponseDtoExtensions.cs:line
>   9    at ourPlatformName.Web.Controllers.QuoteController.Email(Int32
>   proposalId) in
>   D:\code\ourPlatformName_EmailError\testRegion\ourPlatformName.web\app\ourPlatformName.Web\Controllers\QuoteController.cs:line
>   457    at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__12()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<>c__DisplayClass17.b__14()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor
>   actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) 2018-06-21 13:51:30,740 INFO 
>   ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Base.Connector.Handlers.AbstractVERBHandler`1[[ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Base.Infrastructure.Responses.POSTResponseDto`1[[ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Proposals.ProposalQuoteDto,
>   ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs, Version=1.0.1.3789, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]], ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs, Version=1.0.1.3789,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] - Called
>   http://dev.ourPlatformName.api/proposalheader/35245/GetQuote (POST), the
>   response was OK 2018-06-21 13:51:31,548 INFO 
>   ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Base.Connector.Handlers.AbstractVERBHandler`1[[ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Base.Infrastructure.Responses.GETResponseDto`1[[ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Admin.ListChannelDto,
>   ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs, Version=1.0.1.3789, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]], ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs, Version=1.0.1.3789,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] - Called
>   http://dev.ourPlatformName.api/channel/7 (GET), the response was OK
>   2018-06-21 13:51:31,858 INFO 
>   ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Base.Connector.Handlers.AbstractVERBHandler`1[[ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Base.Infrastructure.Responses.LISTResponseDto`1[[ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Party.ProposalDefinition.ListProposalDefinitionDto,
>   ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs, Version=1.0.1.3789, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]], ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs, Version=1.0.1.3789,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] - Called
>   http://dev.ourPlatformName.api/ProposalHeader/35245/ProposalDefinitions
>   (GET), the response was OK 2018-06-21 13:51:33,879 INFO 
>   ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Base.Connector.Handlers.AbstractVERBHandler`1[[ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Base.Infrastructure.Responses.GETResponseDto`1[[ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Party.ProposalDefinition.ProposalDefinitionDto,
>   ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs, Version=1.0.1.3789, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]], ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs, Version=1.0.1.3789,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] - Called
>   http://dev.ourPlatformName.api/ProposalHeader/35245/ProposalDefinition/41457
>   (GET), the response was OK

It works on my colleges' computers fine, but as soon as we try to run the app on my computer (and one other collegues computer) it breaks.

The API is in C# and front end is MVC.

There are other calls that are made to the API that work perfectly fine on my computer, it is just the calls that have their routes defined in one specific file that seem to break. Here is an example of a route definition for a call that works:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Base.Infrastructure.Routing.Base;
using ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.SalesAndReports;

namespace ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Base.Infrastructure.Routing
{
    public class SalesAndReportsRoutes : IDefineRoutes<SalesAndReportsDto>
    {
        public string PluralRoutePrefix { get { return "/SalesAndReports"; } }

        // more code

        public RouteDefinition DetailedChannelInformation
        {
            get
            {
                var path = string.Format("{0}/GetDetailedChannelInformation", PluralRoutePrefix);
                var description = "Get detailed channel information";
                return new RouteDefinition("POST", path, description);//this land up being http://dev.ourPlatformName.api/SalesAndReports/GetDetailedChannelInformation
            }
        }

        //more code

    }
}
```

and here is an example of a route definition for a call that does not work:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Base.Infrastructure.Routing.Base;
using ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Reports.Base;
using ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Reports.Base.Criteria;
using ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Reports;

namespace ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Base.Infrastructure.Routing.Reports
{
    public class ReportRoutes : IDefineRoutes<ReportDto>
    {
        public string PluralRoutePrefix
        {
            get { return "/reports"; }
        }

      //more code

        public RouteDefinition GetReportsByCriteria
        {
            get
            {
                var path = string.Format("{0}/criteria", PluralRoutePrefix);
                var description = "Get a list of all available reports by channel";
                return new RouteDefinition("POST", path, description);// this lands up being http://dev.ourPlatformName.api/reports/criteria
            }
        }

        //more code

    }
}
```

The reason I show this is because, for whatever reason, when I take out the second '/' (as can be seen below), it suddenly works perfectly:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Base.Infrastructure.Routing.Base;
using ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Reports.Base;
using ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Reports.Base.Criteria;
using ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Reports;

namespace ourPlatformName.Api.DTOs.Base.Infrastructure.Routing.Reports
{
    public class ReportRoutes : IDefineRoutes<ReportDto>
    {
        public string PluralRoutePrefix
        {
            get { return "/reports"; }
        }

      //more code

        public RouteDefinition GetReportsByCriteria
        {
            get
            {
                var path = string.Format("{0}criteria", PluralRoutePrefix);
                var description = "Get a list of all available reports by channel";
                return new RouteDefinition("POST", path, description);// this lands up being http://dev.ourPlatformName.api/reportscriteria
            }
        }

        //more code

    }
}
```

Nowhere else (as far as I know) does it require me to make these changes for api calls to work, all the other calls work fine. As mentioned above other computers don't even need to make these changes for these specific calls to work work, so I think it has to be some sort of setting or something installed/not installed on my computer.

We have made sure our regional setting are the same, still no luck.

When we try using postman this is the error we get and error 503 message
[image]

Again, all post/get requests work fine as long as their routesDefinitions are not in the one file mentioned above (as far as I know), and the problematic requests work as soon as I remove the second '/'. All other computers (barring one fellow developers computer) do not share this problem

***EDIT:*** We have discovered that it is not a '/' that causes the issues but rather 'reports/' that causes it. If we change it to anything else, even just remove the s in 'reports' it works perfectly, but is only necessary on my computer and one other - no other laptop has this issue. Some other info that may be relevant, we use Nancy.

Some other relevant data - it was mentioned above that the api logs doesn't even note the attempt to connect - but it will note when a call is made to the api that has a url that is nonsense - so a working call works and is logged, complete nonsense does not work and is logged, but when it has '/reports/' in the url it does not log it and gives an error 503

Comment: Try using an Browser and see if you can get reports using : http://dev.ourPlatformName.api/reports/criteria.  Try on both working and non working PC. Either you aren't getting the results or the wrong browser is on PC.  Try both with IE and Chrome.

Comment: tried with chrome, IE, Edge and Firefox. dev.ourPlatformName.api/reports/criteria gives correct results on all browsers and computers, while  dev.ourPlatformName.api/reports/criteria gives correct data on all browsers on others computers but gives the error message "Service Unavailable \n HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable." on all browsers on my computer

Comment: I suspect there is a header in the request that may be missing.  First I would try to Delete History in the Browser just to make sure there isn't a setting that is affecting the app. If this still doesn't work I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the http headers using IE with the ones when app is run.

Comment: @jdweng did waht you suggested still nothing

Comment: It think issue has to do with the default starting folder.  Usually you would see instead of starting with / you would start with ../  The Webpage starts with the default folder of the URL and then moves from the starting folder.  The folder is in the headers of the request/response.  So if you carefully compare the working and non working with a sniffer you probably will see a difference.  It looks like you are using drives d:\ and f:\.  Maybe the server does not have a d and or f drive.